# Do any commentators say that Adam was not literally the first human being?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, adam

Bereshis seems to imply that Adam was literally the first human being (at least according to the normal translation). Do any commentators (preferably not modern ones) disagree with this?

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%205%20Krakowski.pdf

Comment: I think you mislead in your question. Bereyshit starts with Bereyshit, It says NOTHING about previous worlds, creations or whatever. So after Bereyshit there was only Adam and his descendants. What happened before or outside the Creation Bereyshis talks about - feel free to speculate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[R Israel Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Lipschitz), the Tiferet Yisrael, author of a classic commentary on the Mishna, wrote in 1842 in his essay Ohr HaChayim, that there were other men before Adam

> The Kabbalah teaches that in ancient times several worlds of living
> creatures were created and destroyed on Earth. **Humans were first
> created 974 generations before Adam. With Adam, the world was renewed
> to suit the light of Torah, and mankind became refined enough to
> receive the Torah** (from [here](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/Articles/Article.aspx/4278))

See also this longer description (taken from [this essay](https://www.yutorah.org/_cdn/_shiurim/15-49%20Shuchat.pdf) on YUTorah, pp. 23ff)

> In my humble opinion, those men who lived in prehistoric times, called
> Pre-Adamites in their [i.e., the scientists’] language, are really the
> people of a world before Adam of our world. These are the 974
> generations mentioned in in Shabbat (88b) and Hagigah (13b) who were
> created before this world. ... Since their world was corrupt, they
> were cut off 26 generations before reaching twenty-six generations.
> ... If we reckon that each generation is seventy years, this means
> that their world was destroyed after 6,818 years from its creation.
> These twenty-six generations that were missing in their world were
> completed from Adam to Moses our Teacher ... in which the world was
> prepared and refined well in order to receive the Torah.

Comment: An issue with this ascription is that it leaves the "first tekufah" hanging. Kabbalah relates that there was a previous run of creation, which perhaps included both Divine mission and redemption, but whose creations were not as physical as we are. Now that idea jives very nicely with the idea of prior generations (i.e. they were the first tekufah) but if you say that the prior generations were in our universe, you have to explain why they were created in a physical universe without the capacity to receive the Torah.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that this commentary was censored heavily when it was published and deemed heretical by some like is emphasized in the book by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, z”l, Immortality, Resurrection, and the Age of the Universe on page 8. (Kaplan reprinted the entire commentary in the appendix of the book.) The author of Seder HaDorot HaShalem in the section on Adam HaRishon & the 1st millennium also brings a source referring to the pre-Adamic humans who were present when Adam & Chava were exiled from the Garden. See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133804/7303

Comment: @EthanLeonard Your understanding of what “kabbalah” teaches on this subject is not correct. That isn’t to say that the subject of “spiritual worlds & creatures” isn’t discussed too. But pre-cursors to Adam HaRishon (the species) is discussed in all parts of the Torah. And they were physical. The link I provided above may be helpful.

Comment: @YaacovDeane , I read through your careful and scholarly explanation of the topic and learned something. There are a couple of important points that I hope we can agree are theoretical at best. The idea that the seven nations weren't human, even though their descent is clearly described through Shes, or that each day is a thousand years, despite shtaros saying 5783 "since the creation of the world", or that literally anything from Yovelim can dispute an account from other midrashim (like the one describing the origin of the giants as children of shamchazai and azael), just doesn't hold water.

Comment: @YaacovDeane that's not to say you are wrong in the general point that there may have been proto humans. Just being careful with the sources is all.

Comment: @EthanLeonard You are entitled to your opinion but it is in disagreement with the teachings of Tannaim, Gaonim, Rishonim and Acharonim, many of whom are cited explicitly in that answer. Similarly, the traditions taught by the Mekubalim hold the same way. FYI, the view from Sefer Yovelim is cited by the Abarbanel, a very prominent and authoritative Rishon. Being “careful with the sources” is a given and always presumed.

Answer (score 3):

[R Uri Sherqi](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Oury_Amos_Cherki), citing the Zohar (Wayiqra 10A), states that [humans existed before Adam](https://ravsherki.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1480:14801480-1480&catid=22&Itemid=100512). The Zohar there [states](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01778_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0015_L2):

> ואִי תֵּימָא, הָא כָּל בְּנֵי עָלְמָא מֵאָדָם נַפְקוּ, (לאו הכי דלא)...
>
> And if you will say that all mankind came from Adam (it is not so)...

Comment: That's definitely how Rabbi Sherki takes it, but I wonder if the Zohar means something else by בְּהַאי אַרְעָא עִלָּאָה דְּאִקְרֵי תֵּבֵל - it seems (though I am certainly no expert in the Zohar) that it takes Adam to have been the father of all mankind on this earth, but there are other "lower earths" with different progenitors

Comment: @ba I don't think the surrounding context is required and that's why I omitted it. The conclusion remains the same: that Adam Harishon did not physically father all of mankind. The commentary thereafter only expounds on the idea.

Comment: @ba That is only addressing the concept of the order of creation. Prior to eating from the tree of knowledge of good and evil Adam HaRishon was not clothed in physical, material existence in the fashion that we are today. That is what is meant by ארעא עלאה in this context.

Comment: @Lee The reason why I added it is because I found it odd that the conclusion relies on words in parentheses that don't make a complete sentence

Comment: @YaacovDeane My understanding of the Zohar here is that the land we live in is the ארעה עלאה and that there are literally other layers of other lands that exist below it in parallel, with people who live about 10 years, like the story of Rabbi Nehoray (at the bottom of the page) who fell into the sea and found little people under the sea, and it's those people who aren't descended from Adam... it might not be literal, but that would negate the proof for literal humans not descended from Adam

Comment: @ba Firstly, insofar as I understand English grammar, “it is not so” is a complete sentence. Secondly, R Sherqi quotes those words when citing the Zohar from memory. This gives me the impression that they are a matter of _girsa’ot_ (versions).

Comment: @Lee I was referring to the words in Aramaic לאו הכי דלא ("it isn't so because didn't..."). The two girsa'ot seem to be (from your link) לאו הכי דלא נָחִית אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן לְכֻלְּהוּ אֲרָצוֹת and וְכִי נָחִית אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן לְכֻלְּהוּ אֲרָצוֹת. I was only explaining why I thought adding more words makes it more clear, but it's only a matter of taste

Comment: @ba I have no idea what your understanding is. But from the way you are expressing yourself in English, it sounds like you are taking the words of the Zohar in a literal, physical and material sense. That is not according to traditional Jewish teaching like is part of the subject of Moreh Nevuchim (not Zohar, but allegorical word usage) If your intention is otherwise, at least for me, it’s not coming across.

Comment: I’ve heard Adam came with a soul, other men before him did not have the same type of soul.  So Adam was sent to be a type of messiah

Comment: Does he explain the Mishna in Sanhedrin (4:5) where it says that mankind was created from a single individual?