# Evolution of Humans in Torah

Tags: creation

Is there anywhere in the Torah that mentions in detail any other types of humans (Neanderthals, homo erectus, etc..) and how they evolved, or any interactions?

Comment: Related answer. Scroll down to where it begins discussing the Nachash. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133804/7303

Comment: Like the nephilim? Or the reduction of lifespan?

Comment: @rosends what do you mean here?

Comment: @Eak2449 you ask a few different things -- some people understand the nephillim to be another branch on the human evolutionary tree and some see the slow reduction of the human lifespan as recorded through Genesis as an indication of the evolution of man.

Comment: @rosends wouldn’t that mean that we believe Adam, Noah, Avraham etc.. were different species?

Comment: @Eak2449 no, I don't think so. Evolution within a species doesn't create a new species. If ages of puberty have shifted over time, that doesn't mean that there is a new species of human.