# What both Hashem and the snake said about death after eating the fruit doesn't seem to match what ended up happening?

Tags: death, parashat-bereishit, adam, drush

[Hashem says](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.17):

> וּמֵעֵץ הַדַּעַת טוֹב וָרָע לֹא תֹאכַל מִמֶּנּוּ כִּי בְּיוֹם אֲכׇלְךָ
> מִמֶּנּוּ מוֹת תָּמוּת׃
>
> but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat
> of it: for on the day that thou eatest of it thou shalt surely die.

Leaving aside the point that He doesn't use the word "if", He seems to say that on the day Adam eats, He will definitely die. Adam did not die on the day, nor was it necessarily guaranteed he would *ever* die. In theory, He may have done perfect teshuva or some extremely magnificent good deed and merited eternal life, like many people in history, like Eliyahu Hanavi, and the Jewish people after accepting Torah.

[The snake, l'havdil, says](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.4):

> וַיֹּאמֶר הַנָּחָשׁ אֶל־הָאִשָּׁה לֹא־מוֹת תְּמֻתוּן׃
>
> And the serpent said to the woman, You shall not surely die:

Surely, Adam did die, and the snake didn't specify a time limit to his promise of not dying, so it includes the possibility of being a promise of continued eternal life.

---

Question: do any commentaries, or divrei Torah you've read, note this point that both promises aren't fulfilled as stated, and gives an explanation as to why the Torah does this? Or can someone here put together a few commentaries on these points and try to teach a well researched lesson that **connects these two notable seeming discrepancies**?

Comment: כי אלף שנים בעיניך כיום אתמול

Comment: The short answer is yes. For sources and explanation see the following related answer, particularly at the end. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133804/7303

Comment: I learned that בְּיוֹם אֲכׇלְךָ מִמֶּנּוּ מוֹת תָּמוּת means that on that day, Adam will be found liable to a death penalty but because of the inherent change in mankind, internalizing the yetzer hara, mortality is introduced (hence the concern over eating from teh tree of life).

Comment: Well keep in mind the snake/yetzer hara was just trying to entice Eve to eat from the tree. He could’ve been simply lying when he said “you won’t die” (also midrashically, the snake wanted eve to give Adam the fruit to eat so that he’d die, and then he could marry her. So “you shall not die” is talking to Eve, because she wouldn’t have eaten from the tree according to the snake’s plan, but Adam who will eat from the tree will die. Also different point about your first issue, isn’t it commonly said that מות תמות means that now Adam no longer will live forever?